# Onclick checkbox create dynamic html element with value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectedone(str)
{
    var classes = "";
    $(':checked[class]').each(function(){
       classes = $(this).attr("class");
    });
    var e = document.createElement('strong');
    e.setAttribute('id',str);
    $("#resultthis").append(e);
    row = $("#resultthis").find('#'+str);
    $(row).html(classes);
}
</script>
```

Here for check box:(This one running inside loop)

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="resultthis(this.id);" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" id="<?php echo $a; ?>" class="<?php echo $b; ?>"/>
```

on click on this check box i need to get that class name and create  tag inside (#resultthis) div dynamically and set value for that label same as class name.
My problem was every time i click check box its setting multiple time vaue in side label.
How to resolve this?

Comment: please explain ur problem in simple words.. and what you want to achive ? you want it to set only once ?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to achive this ?
if yes then you should use `.html()` instead of `.append()`

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/tMZ8Q/7/)